# How do we remove kde icons?

Tags: icons

I have installed kde but found a better way to share files and uninstalled kde.

The icons of kde remained in the Application pane.

We want to delete those icons

Comment: We don't know your OS or release, but I'd just switch your icon theme to something else you like (removing `kubuntu-desktop` can still leave some wallpapers, plymouth themes, icons etc behind, but they are treated like any other theme you opt to install; you select to use it, or you don't and then you can remove it).  If the icons were removed on removal of `kubuntu-desktop` you'd have no chosen theme & desktop would look broken, thus having them remain until you select something else is the far better choice.

Comment: Assuming you have now a Gnome desktop, you can change the icon-set with the `gnome-tweaks` app, within its "Appearance" tab.

Comment: Seems I have completely been misunderstood.

Comment: Seems I have completely been misunderstood.